# SeriLog: How to make the path of my log files so that it is the same on other systems too

Tags: c#, .net, serilog

I am trying to use Serilog to add exception logging to a project (.Net Core). But the location I am giving for the log file is a local path on my system. How do I make it so that no matter who has the project the logs are saved?

This is my appsettings.json setting for serilog:

```
"Serilog": {
    "Using": [ "Serilog.Sinks.File" ],
    "MinimumLevel": {
      "Default": "Debug",
      "Override": {
        "Microsoft": "Error",
        "System": "Debug"
      }
    },
    "Enrich": [ "FromLogContext", "WithMachineName", "WithProcessId", "WithThreadId" ],
    "WriteTo": [
      {
        "Name": "File",
        "Args": {
          "path": "Logs\\RestApiLog.log",
          "outputTemplate": "{Timestamp:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff zzz} [{Level}] [{SourceContext}] [{EventId}] {Message}{NewLine}{Exception}",
          "rollOnFileSizeLimit": true,
          "fileSizeLimitBytes": 4194304,
          "retainedFileCountLimit": 15,
          "rollingInterval": "Minute"
        }
      }
    ]
  },
```

Comment: what issue are you facing ? it is not clear from your question .

Comment: @CodingMytra I want to make the path the log file is created generic (Instead of the my local path that I am giving rn). So that it will make a file at the given location on the project

Comment: to me it already seems generic, what problem did you faced ?

Comment: @CodingMytra Please refer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75786934/files-not-being-created-in-the-right-directory-serilog . I have included my full implementation