# Files not being created in the right directory (SeriLog)

Tags: c#, .net, serilog-sinks-file

I am trying to integrate SeriLog into a project so that I can utilize structured logging. I am trying to put the files at a given path but the log files are not being made in the path I am giving. Instead they are being made in a different location

SeriLog config in my Program.cs :

```
var configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
        .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
        .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json")
        .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT") ?? "Production"}.json", true)
        .Build();
var logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
                 .ReadFrom.Configuration(configuration)
                 .Enrich.FromLogContext()
                 .MinimumLevel.Warning()
                 .CreateLogger();
builder.Logging.ClearProviders();
builder.Logging.AddSerilog(logger);
```

My appsettings.json:

```
"Serilog": {
    "Using": [ "Serilog.Sinks.File", "Serilog.Sinks.Console"],
    "MinimumLevel": {
      "Default": "Debug",
      "Override": {
        "Microsoft": "Error",
        "System": "Debug"
      }
    },
    "Enrich": [ "FromLogContext", "WithMachineName", "WithProcessId", "WithThreadId" ],
    "WriteTo": [
      {
        "Name": "Console",
        "Args": {
          "outputTemplate": "[{Timestamp:yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss} {Level:u10}] {Message:lj} {NewLine}{Exception}{NewLine}",
          "theme": "Serilog.Sinks.SystemConsole.Themes.SystemConsoleTheme::Literate, Serilog.Sinks.Console"
        }
      },
      {
        "Name": "File",
        "Args": {
          "path": "Logs\\RestApiLog.log",
          "outputTemplate": "{Timestamp:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff zzz} [{Level}] [{SourceContext}] [{EventId}] {Message}{NewLine}{Exception}",
          "rollOnFileSizeLimit": true,
          "fileSizeLimitBytes": 4194304,
          "retainedFileCountLimit": 15,
          "rollingInterval": "Minute"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
```

My appsetting.Development.json:

```
"Serilog": {
    "Using": [ "Serilog.Sinks.File", "Serilog.Sinks.Console" ],
    "MinimumLevel": {
      "Default": "Debug",
      "Override": {
        "Microsoft": "Error",
        "System": "Debug"
      }
    },
    "Enrich": [ "FromLogContext", "WithMachineName", "WithProcessId", "WithThreadId" ],
    "WriteTo": [
      {
        "Name": "Console",
        "Args": {
          "outputTemplate": "[{Timestamp:yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss} {Level:u10}] {Message:lj} {NewLine}{Exception}{NewLine}",
          "theme": "Serilog.Sinks.SystemConsole.Themes.SystemConsoleTheme::Literate, Serilog.Sinks.Console"
        }
      },
      {
        "Name": "File",
        "Args": {
          "path": "E:\\OneDrive - Octopus Digital\\OC_API\\OmniConnectAPI\\Logs",
          "outputTemplate": "{Timestamp:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff zzz} [{Level}] [{SourceContext}] [{EventId}] {Message}{NewLine}{Exception}",
          "rollOnFileSizeLimit": true,
          "fileSizeLimitBytes": 4194304,
          "retainedFileCountLimit": 15,
          "rollingInterval": "Minute"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
```

I have also implemented a ExceptionHandlingMiddleWare, I am attaching the code to it below:

```
public class ExceptionHandlingMiddleware
{
    public RequestDelegate requestDelegate;
    private readonly ILogger<ExceptionHandlingMiddleware> logger;
    public ExceptionHandlingMiddleware(RequestDelegate requestDelegate, ILogger<ExceptionHandlingMiddleware> logger)
    {
        this.requestDelegate = requestDelegate;
        this.logger = logger;
    }

    public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
    {
        try
        {
            await requestDelegate(context);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            await HandleException(context, ex);
        }
    }
    private Task HandleException(HttpContext context, Exception ex)
    {
        logger.LogError(ex.ToString());
        var errorMessageObject = new { Message = ex.Message, Code = "system_error" };

        var errorMessage = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(errorMessageObject);
        context.Response.ContentType = "application/json";
        context.Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError;
        return context.Response.WriteAsync(errorMessage);
    }
}
```

I have also added this line to progam.cs so that I can use this middleware:
`app.UseMiddleware(typeof(ExceptionHandlingMiddleware));`

I am also attaching an image so that you can see where the files should be created and where they are actually being created:
[![The files are not being created in the log folder]

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/UTfwR.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UTfwR.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I immediately notice is that your path has a "logical" error.

You forgot to close your path at `"E:\\OneDrive - Octopus Digital\\OC_API\\OmniConnectAPI\\Logs"`, it should look like `"E:\\OneDrive - Octopus Digital\\OC_API\\OmniConnectAPI\\Logs\\"`.

You can see this perfectly in your files that were created, at the very beginning it says `"Logs"`, the program thinks `"\\Logs"` is the beginning of a file and not a folder.

Answer (score 0):

Okay so it was actually quite a basic mistake I was making, instead of           `"path": "E:\\OneDrive - Octopus Digital\\OC_API\\OmniConnectAPI\\Logs",`
in my appsettings.Development.json I just needed to change it to
`"path": "E:\\OneDrive - OctopusDigital\\OC_API\\OmniConnectAPI\\Logs\\LogFile_.log"`
I think the problem was that I was not specifying what I wanted to name the file itself.